# How to get IP address of host inside a python file when it is executed in that host?

Tags: python, ip, ip-address, host

I am executing same python file in different hosts.

Inside the python file there is `bind`. The first time I am executing this file in 'H1' host and next time I am executing in 'H2' host.While executing in 'H1' host I want to use IP address of H1 for binding.While executing in 'H2' host, I want to use IP address of 'H2' host for binding.

So at the place of IP address what should I give so that I will get required IP address that is IP of H1 while this python file is executed in H1 and IP of H2 while this file is executed in H2?

Comment: This is very unclear.

Comment: Can't you leave the IP out when binding, and it will automatically use the host's IP?

Comment: @aIKid my python file is a server.I am executing this in different hosts.I want ip address of that host inside my server file for binding.

Comment: Are you asking for the IP address of the server on which your script is being run.

Comment: @neethuK import socket; socket.gethostbyaddr(socket.gethostname()) I know what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we are talking IPv4 addresses, then in most cases you don't need to specify the host address to `bind()`. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html):

> For IPv4 addresses, two special forms are accepted instead of a host address: the empty string represents `INADDR_ANY`, and the string `'<broadcast>'` represents `INADDR_BROADCAST`.

It's quite likely that you just want to supply the empty string (which will make your service listen on all available interfaces).

If you still need to know the hostname of the machine the script is running on, you could use [`socket.gethostname()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.gethostname):

> Return a string containing the hostname of the machine where the Python interpreter is currently executing.
>
> If you want to know the current machine’s IP address, you may want to use `gethostbyname(gethostname())`. This operation assumes that there is a valid address-to-host mapping for the host, and the assumption does not always hold.

Comment: Note that many machines have more than one IP address (not even counting 127.0.0.1). INADDR_ANY will listen on all available addresses; if you don't want that behavior, you need to specify the address on which to bind.

Answer (score 0):

Do you simply want the IP address of the machine that the python script is running on?  This answer is OS dependent, but could be used on *nix systems.  It could also be adapted for windows:

```
try:
   o1 = subprocess.check_output("/sbin/ifconfig eth0 | awk '/inet/ { print $2 } ' | sed -e s/addr://", shell=True).split()[0]
except:
   o1 = None #parsing failed for some reason
```